# How to overlay a plot on over an image?

Tags: r, image, plot, raster

I am trying to overlay an image over a forecast plot. The forecast object does not seem to have

```
library(quantmod)

Stock_df<-as.data.frame(getSymbols(Symbols = "AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = "2017-05-06", env = NULL))
fit <- auto.arima(Stock_df$AAPL.Close,ic="bic")
fit.forecast <- forecast(fit)
library(jpeg)
my_image=readJPEG("Myimage.jpg")

plot.new()
lim <- par()
rasterImage(my_image, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4], main= "AAPL")
line(fit.forecast)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

How do I simply overlay a forecast object over an image?

**SOLUTION**

After some trial and error and a bit of research. I found the following solution.

```
plot.new()
lim <- par()
rasterImage(my_image, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4], main= "AAPL")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(fit.forecast)
```

I hope this solution helps

Comment: When answering your own question, you should enter it as a separate answer - not an edit to the question

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to dww's suggestion, I am answering my own question after a bit of research (i.e., trial and error).

```
plot.new()
lim <- par()
rasterImage(my_image, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4], main= "AAPL")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(fit.forecast)
```